# How to implement a half-manual, half-automatic animation in React Native in a performant way?

Tags: react-native, animation

I need to create an animation in React Native which is best described as follows:

- A user grabs some UI item and drags it from its original position.
- While the user moves it, there is also some rotation, the UI item rotates around the Z-axis according to its motion on the XY plane.
- When the user releases the item, both its position and its rotation are animated back to their original values (a "fire-and-forget" animation).

This is similar to a "pull down to refresh" UI widget. While the user is pulling down, we have both the Y translation and the rotation of the loading wheel coupled to the touch movement, and when the user lets go, there is a fire-and-forget animation without control by the user.

**How would I implement this in a performant way?**

I'm thinking of something like this:

1. We store the user's motion in the state of the component. With every move of the touch, the UI is re-rendered (not sure if that is performant).
2. When the user releases the touch, we use `Animated.timing` to generate the fire-and-forget animation.

Because of 2., the value in the state needs to be an `Animated.Value` instance. I'm not sure if 1. can be implemented in a performant way, using an `Animated.Value` as a state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is (of course): use `react-native-reanimated`. With this library, you have complete, declarative control over native animations and their interactions with gestures.

This is an example app which has what I was looking for:

[image]

[Here](https://github.com/software-mansion/react-native-reanimated/blob/master/Example/imageViewer/index.js) is the source code.